# Read files in sdcard using existing applications

Tags: android, file

I am trying to learn android studio. I know basics of read and write text files or any such files. I wish to know how to create dialog box like in ES file explorer application. When, I click on file, I **wish to open dialog** box as in image below. And when I click on app (say Adobe Acrobat) I want that file to open in **Adobe Acrobat**

[image: Dialog Box]

So far, I have written code that lists existing files in particular folder

```
public class ShowList extends ListActivity {
    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File Dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Myfolder");
        ListDir(Dir);
    }

    void ListDir(File f)
    {
        File[] files =f.listFiles();
        fileList.clear();
        for (File file:files) {
            fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> DirList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fileList);
        setListAdapter(DirList);

    }
}
```

Comment: I have written code to display files in particular folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer. It shows chooser for .txt files

```
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(filepath), "text/plain");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(target);
```